# "Migrate reset" not working when there is an error in code

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration, laravel-5.8

In basic Laravel application, in User class I added:

> use SoftDeletes;

Application is no longer working because there is no 'deleted_at' column in the User table of MySql database. I'm trying to add this column by dropping all tables and recreating them (or by dropping all tables):

> artisan migrate:refresh --seed
>
> artisan migrate:reset
>
> artisan migrate:fresh

In all cases I get an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: select exists(select * from `users` where `email` = user@gmail.com and `users`.`deleted_at` is null) as `exists`)

which I don't understand. If I'm reverting migrations, artisan should only call down() method on my User class which is:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

and dropping table shouldn't fail if column is not found.

P.S. I'm using docker-compose to run php, mysql, artisan, composer, nginx and nodejs - if that could matter.

Comment: have you tried `php artisan migrate:fresh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original answer given was incorrect as the question is also somewhat incorrect, after discussing in chat, we found that the author had the migrations also in the AppServiceProvider which was preventing actual migrations from happening via the CLI.

You can read [the chat here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200561/discussion-between-ian-and-uros). Removing the artisan calls from AppServiceProvider solved this

Comment: There is same error for all migrate commands, including migrate:fresh

Comment: @Uros the fresh command acts differently to refresh, have you tried this?

Comment: @Uros I can't imagine why `migrate:fresh` doesn't work as it forcefully drops all tables and starts everything over. `migrate:refresh` however rolls back migrations in which it will throw this error.

It looks like this error is unrelated to your migrations in that case and it's code elsewhere.

Comment: When I comment out this one line of code ('use SoftDeletes;'), migrations are running without problem. I agree with you that it should be an error. Maybe problem is with running it inside docker

Comment: @Uros Do you by any chance have any queries running in your service providers?

Comment: Yes. I have AppServiceProvider with boot() method that is calling Artisan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200561/discussion-between-ian-and-uros).

Answer (score 1):

have you added the soft deletes in the migrations as well?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->softDeletes();
        ...
    });
}
```